# C# Submit Button in Topic Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, form-submit

I have a form in my master page declared:

```
 <form name="search" method="post" action="searchresults.aspx" id="searchform" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
```

I have a text box in a control called TopicSearchTreeControl and the textbox within there is declared as:

```
 <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordSearch" value="Enter keyword(s) or pub. number" runat="server" class="watermark" />
```

But when the user hits enter on the keyboard to submit the form and the page_load function in searchresults.aspx.cs is called:

```
keywords = Request.Form["keywords"];
```

The above line is always blank.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's being posted, Request[] will find it, it will search all Request collections:

```
//should work
keywords = Request["keywordSearch"];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
keywords = Request.Form["keywordSearch"];
```

Comment: keywords = Request.Form["ctl00$cphLeftPanel$TopicSearchTreeControl$keywordSearch"];